# android.speech package to just determine whether there is speech rather than using the full process of also converting to text

Tags: android, speech-recognition, speech

this is my first post so I hope is of interest! I am basically hoping to determine if there are people in proximity by capturing voices/conversations, note I am not interested in what they are saying. So, I was wondering if it would be possible to use the android.speech package to just determine whether there is speech rather than using the full process of also converting to text. Any thoughts on this or any other options that may be possible? I am also looking to use this as a background service, i.e. work whilst in a user’s pocket. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[onBeginningOfSpeech](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognitionListener.html#onBeginningOfSpeech%28%29) is called by the speech recognition provider once it thinks that there is a beginning of speech. If you are not interested in the content of the speech or even when it ends then call immediately [stopListening](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer.html#stopListening%28%29). Both of these methods are in `android.speech`.